# XNA 2D Basic collision list

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I am a beginner in the programming world and right now I am trying out XNA programming in C# and right now I am working on a basic game where the player is a airplane or spaceship and you have to shoot down meteors.

At the moment I am trying out box collision detection and I can't quite figure it out, I dont relly know how to get the position of every single item in a list, and I need your help!

So basically I have a shiptexture and a meteortexture. The modeltexture gets drawn 10 times and it gets random position. I want to make rectangles around each meteor but i cant figure out how. I tried with the foreach loop shown down below but ONLY one meteor works when i collide with it. Sorry if my English isn't the best, and i appreciate everyone's help!

```
List<Vector2> meteor_pos = new List<Vector2>();

              //loadcontent
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                meteor_pos.Add(new Vector2(myRnd.Next(800), myRnd.Next(600)));
                double tmp_angle = (myRnd.Next(1000) * Math.PI * 2) / 1000.0;
                double tmp_speed = 0.5 + 3.0 * (myRnd.Next(1000) / 1000.0);
                meteor_speed.Add(new Vector2((float)(tmp_speed * Math.Cos(tmp_angle)),
                (float)(tmp_speed * Math.Sin(tmp_angle))));
            }

              //protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
              for (int i = 0; i < meteor_pos.Count; i++)
                {
                    meteor_pos[i] += meteor_speed[i];
                    Vector2 v = meteor_pos[i];
                    //Outside the screen?
                    if (v.X < -80)
                        v.X = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width + 80;
                    if (v.X > graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width + 80)
                        v.X = -80;
                    if (v.Y < -60)
                        v.Y = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height + 60;
                    if (v.Y > graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height + 60)
                        v.Y = -60;
                    //Uppdate the list
                    meteor_pos[i] = v;

               }
                foreach (var item in meteor_pos)      
                 {
                     meteor_rect = new Rectangle((int)item.X, (int)item.Y, gfx_meteor.Width, gfx_meteor.Height);
                 }

                gfx_rect = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, gfx.Width, gfx.Height);

                if (gfx_rect.Intersects(meteor_rect))
                {
                    position.X = 0;
                    position.Y = 0;
                }

    //protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)

                for (int i = 0; i < meteor_pos.Count; i++)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(gfx_meteor, meteor_pos[i], null, Color.White, 0,
                new Vector2(gfx_meteor.Width / 2, gfx_meteor.Height / 2), 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
            }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is pretty confusing and you're going to want to create a class, at minimum probably a sprite class that handles a position and some other basic info.

However to fix your current issue, you're overwriting the value to meteor_rect in your foreach loop and then only checking the collision one time at the end.

so switch your code to look like this:

```
gfx_rect = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, gfx.Width, gfx.Height);

foreach (var item in meteor_pos)      
    {
        meteor_rect = new Rectangle((int)item.X, (int)item.Y, gfx_meteor.Width, gfx_meteor.Height);

        if (gfx_rect.Intersects(meteor_rect))
            {
                position.X = 0;
                position.Y = 0;
            }
    }
```

but like I said please look up a basic tutorial to help you out :)